# Same model for two tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I set the name of my table in my model in the constructor:

```
public function __construct($section, $attributes = array(), $exists = false){

    parent::__construct($attributes, $exists);

    $this->table = $section;
}
```

Later on in the class I use this method:

```
public function getEdit($id){

    return $this->find($id);
}
```

But it fails:

```
Missing argument 1 for MyModel::__construct()
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you ever override a method that is provided by another class, you should add your own parameters to the end of the parameter list as optional parameters. The reason being that there will likely be code that relies on the old implementation. You can't expect it to know your new implementation, so you must add your own stuff to the end (and optional because the existing implementation won't be supplying it).

As such, change your constructor to:

```
public function __construct($attributes = array(), $exists = false, $section = null){
    parent::__construct($attributes, $exists);
    $this->table = $section;
}
```

And you should find it works. Obviously you'll have to update your code to pass $seciton as the last parameter now, too.

Comment: This does not work, I pass in the vars like so $this->model = new TestModel(array(), false, 'table_a'); The model still looks for null, and just sets the model to the default name for the table TestModel(s)

Comment: It seems argument 3 is not being passed for some reason?

Comment: Hmm, it does seem to set the table correctly, more of a problem happens when I: return $this->find($id); This is where its looking for a mysterious 3rd attribute

Comment: Ahh okay that's a different problem. So the real underlying issue is that you're overriding the constructor on an Eloquent model and expecting the core Eloquent methods to use your new functionality, and they won't. I don't think this will work the way you want it to. It may work some of the time (e.g. if you manually crate your own instance) and fail others (when the framework is responsible for creating an instance). As such I wouldn't rely on this to work. What's the use-case for using one model for two possible tables? Can you not create one model and extend it with the two specific cases?

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's what I'm going to have to do. So would you recommend this: Create a model for each table, declare the table in each model, then get the model to extend a general model that has all my methods?

Comment: As long as the base model only contains exact shared functionality, I don't see why it would be an issue. The problem could come in the future if the tables/models start to diverge. If you use PHP 5.4+ you could try a trait instead...?